# Get days between tow dates

Tags: oracle, plsql, char

Have a date in the table with format 10/04/14
then use this `to_char(nameofcolumn, 'yyyymmdd'))` to get this

20140410

Now, need rest a this value the sydate

I use this

```
select nameofcolumn,
to_char(nameofcolumn, 'yyyymmdd')) - to_char(sysdate, 'yyyymmdd') AS days
from
table;
```

But te result for example 07/07/14 return 300 days when is 90

Answer (score 1):

Why are you converting these into strings? You can perform basic date arithmetic without converting them:

```
select nameofcolumn,
       nameofcolumn - sysdate AS days
from
table;
```

Comment: LOL, i don't know why conver this to char, my bad and thx u for the simple solution :)

Answer (score 1):

I can't add comments so i will post a little addition as a separate answer.

```
SELECT to_date('07/07/2014','dd/mm/yyyy') - SYSDATE AS days FROM dual;
```

would return a number with a floating point instead of an integer. You've got to do either

```
SELECT trunc(to_date('07/07/2014','dd/mm/yyyy') - SYSDATE) AS days FROM dual;
```

or

```
SELECT to_date('07/07/2014','dd/mm/yyyy') - trunc(SYSDATE) AS days FROM dual;
```

depeding on what exactly you want to achieve.